# Can we use different java version library in application

Tags: java

My system has `java version "1.6.0_45"` set as default *environment variable* `path` which I can't change.

And I want to use libraries of `jdk1.8.0..`. For example:

```
Path source = ....
Path target = ....
Files.copy(source, target)
```

The package `java.nio.file.*` came into existence during `java 1.7`, so how can I use these libraries in my application.

Comment: You cannot use the standard library of Java 7 or 8 with a Java 6 runtime environment. Why not just use the Java 8 runtime environment? Just because Java 6 is in the `PATH` that doesn't mean you cannot use a different Java version.

Comment: Check this solution, it might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050538/how-to-run-a-specific-version-of-java-with-a-program

Comment: @Jesper We can't do that as it will affect other application.

Comment: Are you running the application under a  server such as JBoss, Tomcat etc?

Comment: @Omoro Nope, It's a normal application and i'm running in UNIX.

Comment: You can set PATH and JAVA_HOME explictly for a single invocation.  This does not have to influence other programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this.

A JRE has both Java and C code which go together, so you must change how your program is invoked to use Java 8.

Note however, that there usually is ways to get around these things but the way to do so depends strongly on the operating system and what level of access to the surrounding environment.  For instance, it is very common for scripts to respect a JAVA_HOME environment pointing to a locally installed Java 8 JVM, or you can provide your application with its own JVM enclosed.

Comment: You may want to add additional information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to build app using 1.6 and trying to use 1.8 there is no way to do this.

if you are trying to build JAVA app in 1.8 then follow the steps

1. Create a start.bat or start.sh file depends on your OS.
2. export or set JAVA_HOME to the right path
3. set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%
4. script to start your application.

i have the same scenario building app in diff Version of JVM, so i just created a Bat file to change the path when ever i wish.

hope this should work for you.
if not add more info

Comment: I can't do this as it will affect other application.

Comment: Have a look at following GITHUB `https://github.com/psramkumar/utils` jdk.bat and jdk.sh files used to switch between diff JDK. make sure to add them in Path